Ulkit - adding top nav sub-menu and off canvas accordian type sub-menu
I am working on a website using a html theme that uses Ulkit for menus / submenus.
The source / page example is here: https://html-theme-soutien.vercel.app/category.html
I can see in the .css that some code is in place for top nav sub-nav but I do not know how to implement it.
I do not see any code / provision for off canvas clickable accordian sub menu option.
I have looked / tried the ulkit code on their website but cannot get it to work.
If anybody could suggest links to working examples and / or .css / .js or html code that might help it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
